# How to make the zoom smooth in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery zoom for image viewer. the image is zooming on click on image.
I want to make the zoom smoothly. How can i do this?

code:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.zoom.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $('#ex4').zoom({ on:'toggle' });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
<div class="zoom" id="ex4">
    <img src="images/element.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `duration` option, in this way to zoom effect will take more and seems more smooth.

Ref:

> duration  120 The fadeIn/fadeOut speed of the large image.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ex1').zoom({
        on: 'toggle',
        duration: 1000
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/YDart/

Answer (score 2):

Or like I am using this plugin. It has a lot of setting options, and I think everyone finds what it needs

http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

Answer (score 1):

That comes down to your browsers computing power I'm afraid, because the zoom library seems very smooth to me (http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/).

Also it appears the library isn't 'zooming' but rather fading in a larger graphic to give the same effect.

Sorry mate, no real way to optimise this from what I can see.